# MongoDB - How can I define a field as unique and nullable in MongoDB?

Tags: database, typescript, mongodb

i am writing in typescript,

i am trying this in member model:

```
mail: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    nullable: true,
    default: null,
      }
```

Comment: Is [schema validation in mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: @ray schema type is ok, i cant use nullable true, default null and unique true..